# GoLang for loop with floats creates error

Tags: for-loop, floating-point, go, rounding

Can someone explain the following. I have a function in go that accepts a couple of float64 and then uses this value to calculate a lot of other values. The function looks like

```
func (g *Geometry) CalcStresses(x, zmax, zmin float64)(Vertical)
```

the result is put into a struct like

```
type Vertical struct {
    X float64
    Stresses []Stress
}
```

Now the funny thing is this. If I call the function like this;

```
for i:=14.0; i<15.0; i+=0.1{
    result := geo.CalcStresses(i, 10, -10)
}
```

then I get a lot of results where the Stress array is empty, antoher interesting detail is that x sometimes shows like a number with a LOT of decimals (like 14.3999999999999999998)

However, if I call the function like this;

```
for i:=0; i<10; i++{
    x := 14.0 + float64(i) * 0.1
    result := geo.CalcStresses(x,10,-10)
}
```

then everything is fine.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: You might find these resources helpful: http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf and http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: wow, thanks Volker, this definitely is the most comprehensive answer I could have had :-) Great paper, thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all real numbers can be represented precisely in binary floating point format, therefore looping over floating point number is asking for trouble.

From Wikipedia on [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

> The fact that floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and that floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, leads to many surprising situations. This is related to the finite precision with which computers generally represent numbers.
>
> For example, the non-representability of 0.1 and 0.01 (in binary) means that the result of attempting to square 0.1 is neither 0.01 nor the representable number closest to it.

[This code](http://play.golang.org/p/y59-AV1HhU)

```
for i := 14.0; i < 15.0; i += 0.1 {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

produces this

```
14
14.1
14.2
14.299999999999999
14.399999999999999
14.499999999999998
14.599999999999998
14.699999999999998
14.799999999999997
14.899999999999997
14.999999999999996
```

You may use [math.big.Rat](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Rat) type to represent rational numbers accurately.

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/c92mz8NGZD)

```
x := big.NewRat(14, 1)
y := big.NewRat(15, 1)
z := big.NewRat(1, 10)

for i := x; i.Cmp(y) < 0; i = i.Add(i, z) {
    v, _ := i.Float64()
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```